# request attribute variables are not replaced by their value when table set through javascript using innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I created html table using javascript by replacing inner HTML of div tag:

```
document.getElementById("table2").innerHTML = ".+${filename}+...+$id}...";
//whole table html inside
```

The table was created but the request attributes accessed like `${filename}` or `${id}` are not replaced by their value but remained as it is in the table.

Comment: Javascript doesn't do variable interpolation inside strings. You have to use concatenation with `+`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use concatenation, not interpolation. Javascript is not PHP or Perl.

```
document.getElementById("table2").innerHTML = "...." + filename + "..." + id + "...";
```

Comment: Actually, filename and id are request attribute so when i put them in the table (as ${filename} and ${id}) they get replaced by their values in the table. But when I create table using java script, in the html page these variables are not replaced by their values.

Comment: Are you talking about PHP variables? PHP runs on the server when creating the page, Javascript runs on the server after the page has been sent to the client.

Comment: In PHP, the syntax is `{$filename}`, not `${filename}`. And it has to be in a doublequoted PHP string or a here-doc.

Comment: and it works when i create table as a simple HTML without using java script to populate innerHTML